# STR_TO_DATE doesn't work from mysql using command line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to execute an UPDATE statement from a batch file. The statement looks like this:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword -e "UPDATE db.table SET creationDate = STR_TO_DATE(creationDate,'%d/%m/%Y');"
```

but when I execute the code, the output is:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword -e "UPDATE db.table SET creationDate = STR_TO_DATE(creationDate,'m/%Y');"
```

Any idea why the %d/%m format is ignored?

Comment: In a batch file? I think you have to escape the percentage signs with more percentage signs.

Comment: Totally right. Solved adding one more percentage sign for each component. Thank you! =)